# Windows Phone 8.1 SolidColorBrush and Trigger

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using VS2013 creating a Windows Phone 8.1 App, I want to change the color property of some controls from the cs files, and I have encountered two problems:

1.I create `<Application.Resources>` in App.xaml, I could never find `<Style.Triggers>` as the instructions online says(is it taken out recently?

2.I want to change the foreground color of a particular button in the .cs file, and I used `button_1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)`, but the compiler reports error saying "The name 'Colors' does not exist in current context", I also tried RGB and #ffffffff and so on, nothing works.

Screenshot of the second problem:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the fully qualified name of Colors, like this.

```
button_1.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Red);
```

Or add a using directive to the top of your code window.

```
using Windows.UI;
```

See [Using Directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) on MSDN